# How the javascript array display result with new line

Tags: reactjs

Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated!!
In imageList.js, the following {images} is an array.
How can the return of an string "div" of an array return the below image:

return {images}

display this result like if there is a "\n" new line for each record?:

```
        import React from 'react';

    const ImageList = props => {
      const images =   props.images.map((image) => {
        return <img src={image.urls.regular} />
        });
        console.log(props.images)
        return <div>{images}</div>;
    }

    export default ImageList;
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

for this you are creating `img` elements and depending on your css they are taking the entire container width. Solving this would require specifying image sizes for example

```
div{
display: grid;
grid-template-column: repeat(3, 1fr)
}
```

or

```
img{
width: 45%;
}
```

but in the end, it depends on your styling

Answer (score 0):

Your images list is displayed correctly but you miss the css for it.
you can use the GridList or gird system of [material ui](https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/#grid-list)
or you build your own design.

here is a sample

```
<GridList cellHeight={160} className={classes.gridList} cols={3}>
  {imagess.map((image) => (
  <GridListTile key={image.key} cols={image.cols || 1}>
     <img src={image.img} alt={image.title} />
  </GridListTile>
  ))} </GridList>
```

in the link below you can find more usefull information.